# Google Apps Script - get value of cell offset from a given cell in argument

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I spent some time on this but could not find the answer I was looking for. I am writing a cost calculator, where not everybody contributed to every cost. I use a check box to count whether a person is a contributor to a given cost, and at the end there is a formula that takes an indefinite number of arguments (using `arguments` in JS), and tallies up all checked boxes and adds to the sum for a given person. You will see what I mean below, with screenshots, code snippet, and my gSheet. All I am trying to figure out is, if an argument (checkbox) is checked, to add to my sum the value of a different cell from a different row, but same column, as my checkbox.

I am able to use the `INDIRECT` syntax if I am writing the script directly in cell, but am trying to use GAS and call the `if` function, so I can add the if (checkbox) then statement. Any help is appreciated.

Bonus points if you can help me figure out syntax so I don't have to add every cell's value as a comma-separated argument, and instead add a range as an array of arguments.

Please look below and see if you can help me figure out what syntax I am looking for.

[Screenshot of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilwvb.png)

[Link to sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wc5vSHMHWseOYK927_HMP2aA-CIN0fY1xFk0ci4RJE4/edit?usp=sharing)

Code:

```
function addIt() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    //this is where I want to add a 'perPerson' that is a value offset from the the cell position of a given argument
    //var perPerson = [?????]
    if (arguments[i] == true) {
      sum += perPerson;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal. Can you provide the sample output values you expect as an image? Because in your sample image, `#REF!` is shown. From `All I am trying to figure out is, if an argument (checkbox) is checked, to add to my sum the value of a different cell from a different row, but same column, as my checkbox.`. in your goal, you want to sum the rows in one column?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for the sum of all 'Per Person' fields, for any column that is checked. 

So, 'Person A' would have a total that is $16 + $66 + $ 80 + $100 ($262). This is because 'Item 1', 'Item 2', Item 4', and 'Item 6' are checked.

'Person F' would have $16 + $75 + $80 + $125 + $100 ($396). This is because Items 1, 3, 4, 5, and 6 are checked.

So, if a box is checked, the 'Per Person' number for that column gets added to that person's total. 

Thanks,

Comment: Sheet has been updated with comments for clarity

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, please put `=addIt(B3:G3)` to a cell "H3". By this, the value is put to the cells "H3".

```js
function addIt(values) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var v = sheet.getRange("B10:G10").getValues()[0];
  return values[0].reduce((s, c, i) => s += c == true ? v[i] : 0, 0);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample, please put `=addIt(B3:G8)` to a cell "H3". By this, the values are put to the cells "H3:H8".

```js
function addIt(values) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var v = sheet.getRange("B10:G10").getValues()[0];
  return values.map(r => r.reduce((s, c, j) => s += c == true ? v[j] : 0, 0));
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does indeed work. I don't really use ternary operators and am confused by the `0:0`, so let me sit down and wrap my head around this. 

Perhaps a simpler question in addition to your (very good) answer: what is the best way to refer to a given cell offset? So, for example, if B3 == true, return B[3+7]? I hope I am making sense. I was able to write something easily in the cell with `=INDEIRECT("R[+7]C",FALSE)`...is there an equivalent behavior in Google Apps Script? Thank you!!

Comment: @patrickgilsf About your new question of `Perhaps a simpler question in addition to your (very good) answer`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do about your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: No worries Tanaike, and thanks for your help. I just wanted to write something like:
if (B3 == true) {arguments += B[3+7]}...but I couldn't figure out how to do a relative cell offset with a given cell as the argument. Honestly not a huge deal, as this is working....I appreciate you taking the time!! Thanks!

Comment: @patrickgilsf Thank you for replying. If you have a question for my answer, I would like to support you. Feel free to tell me. But when I cannot understand the question, if you can cooperate to make me understand it, I'm glad. About your new question of `I just wanted to write something like:`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I responded earlier, but in the wrong place. Here:

If go to my sheet I will try to give a clear example: (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…) if (x == true) {   return [the value of the cell that is 7 rows down from x] } so if x is B3, return the value in B10 ($25.00). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I responded earlier, but in the wrong place. Here:

If go to my sheet I will try to give a clear example: (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…) if (x == true) {   return [the value of the cell that is 7 rows down from x] } so if x is B3, return the value in B10 ($25.00). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @patrickgilsf Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot click the link from `If go to my sheet I will try to give a clear example: (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Grand Total Without using any cells functions

```
function grandTotals() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 3;
  const ihA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const chA = sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let imidx = {};
  ihA.forEach((h, i) => { imidx[h] = i; });
  let csidx = {};
  chA.forEach((h, i) => { csidx[h] = i; })
  let gt = { pA: [], iA: [] };
  //collecting cell data
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (j > 0) {
        if (c == "TRUE") {
          if (!gt.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
            gt[r[0]] = [];
            gt[r[0]].push({ item: ihA[j], cost: chA[j] })
            gt.pA.push(r[0]);
          } else {
            gt[r[0]].push({ item: ihA[j], cost: chA[j] })
          }
          if (!gt.hasOwnProperty(ihA[j])) {
            gt[ihA[j]] = { cost: chA[j], count: 1 };
            gt.iA.push(ihA[j])
          } else {
            gt[ihA[j]].count += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  //calculating grand totals
  let g =  gt.pA.map(p => {
    return [p,parseInt(gt[p].reduce((a, obj) => {
      a += gt[obj.item].cost / gt[obj.item].count;
      return a;
    }, 0))]
  });
  sh.getRange(sr,8,g.length,g[0].length).setValues(g);
  const end = "is near";
  console.log(g);
}

[ [ 'Person A', 408 ],
  [ 'Person B', 808 ],
  [ 'Person C', 150 ],
  [ 'Person E', 25 ],
  [ 'Person F', 708 ] ]
```

Starting Data:

|  | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | $100.00 | $200.00 | $300.00 | $400.00 | $500.00 | $600.00 |
| Person A | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| Person B | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| Person C | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| Person D | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Person E | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Person F | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

Grand Totals:

| Person | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | 408 |
| Person B | 808 |
| Person C | 150 |
| Person E | 25 |
| Person F | 708 |

Comment: Fascinating approach, thanks Cooper!